# Threads and global variables: Why do I get 10 or 15 as output although i don't use the variable y?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, global-variables, thread-synchronization

I know that both threads can use the global variable `k` and `p` and also that after the CPU-time of one thread expired the other thread gets CPU-time and that's why I get different outputs like 9, 10 but I do not understand how the outputs 10 comes from. I guess it's because of the variable `y` although I don't use it.

```
int k=2;
int* p;
   void t1_f1(void){
   int x=3;
   p=&x;
   sleep(1);
}

void t1_f2(void){
   int y=5;
   k++;
   sleep(1);
}

void* t1_main(void* args){
   t1_f1();
   t1_f2();
   return NULL;
}

void* t2_main(void* args){
   sleep(1);
   k=k* *p;
   printf("%d \n", k);
   return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
   pthread_t threads[2];
   pthread_create(threads+1, NULL, t2_main, NULL);
   pthread_create(threads, NULL, t1_main, NULL);
   pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);
   pthread_join(threads[1],NULL);
   exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Also, `sleep()` is not a synchronization call.  [It provides no guarantees at all about visibility of changes to/from other threads.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program has **UB** ([**`Undefined Behavior`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)) and therefore you cannot expect any consistent output at all.

**2 Examples for UB in your code:**

1. in `t1_f1` you assign the global `p` to the address of a local variable (`x`). When `x` goes out of the scope when the function returns, you'll have a dandling pointer, and dereferencing it (`*p`) in `t2_main` is UB.
2. `t2_main` might execute before `p` is initialized at all (it is not initialized at the global scope where it is defined). In this case it's also UB to dereference it.
   Note that as commented [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74752972/threads-and-global-variables-why-do-i-get-10-or-15-as-output-although-i-dont-u/74753053#comment131930933_74752972) by @AndrewHenle, `sleep()` is not a threads synchronization call.